# Can my xubuntu installation be converted to standard Ubuntu?

Tags: gui, xubuntu

I currently have xubuntu installed on my netbook, and I'm considering converting it to the standard vanilla Ubuntu. Is this possible? If so, how do I start?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You'll simply need to install the `ubuntu-desktop` meta-package. This installs all the nessisary packages for a "Vanilla" Ubuntu Desktop. `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` Once this has been completed you can restart your computer. At the login screen you can switch from XFCE to Ubuntu Desktop under the Session dropdown. Doing so will load the Gnome desktop.

If you're satisfied with Ubuntu Desktop and wish to remove xubuntu you can always remove the meta package `xubuntu-desktop` which will remove the meta-package. If you wish to remove all the packages from the xubuntu-desktop meta package you'll have to remove those by hand. [An updated list of all the packages by distrobution](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/puregnome) is available simply copy the line for your version of Ubuntu

Comment: Would it be better to use autoremove instead of remove since autoremove will also remove the orphaned dependencies?

Comment: @Jasper `xubuntu-desktop` isn't considered orphaned since you can have multiple Desktop Environments on one installation. However, if you remove `xubuntu-desktop` meta-package it should take out all packages that aren't inner-dependent for packages outside of the meta-package. One may need to run autoremove after removing `xubuntu-desktop` if there are any orphaned packages though.

Comment: Removing the xubuntu-desktop meta-package will not remove the Xfce desktop. It will only remove the xubuntu-desktop package itself. You will need to remove all the xfce and xubuntu specific packages individually to remove Xubuntu.

Comment: @charlie-tca You're right, it only remove the meta package unless xubuntu-desktop was installed with aptitude which isn't available in the distribution anymore. I've updated my answer to reflect that and the "proper" way to remove all the xubuntu packages

Comment: What about upgrades? Will they work properly, too?

Comment: Would there be any conflicting daemons or startup scripts by having both ubuntu-desktop and xubuntu-desktop (regarding 14.04) installed?

Answer (score 5):

You can simply install all standart ubuntu package with `apt`

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

Then when you feel good with your new environement

```
sudo apt purge xubuntu-desktop
sudo apt autoremove
```

And don't forget to reconfigure [GDM3](https://packages.debian.org/en/sid/gdm3) login

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

Also you may want to change Ubuntu loading screen. It is realy easy, check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489459/how-do-i-change-the-ubuntu-loading-screen/489469#489469).

Finally reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 3):

Install ubuntu-desktop.
To uninstall xubuntu, follow these guidelines: (select the right ubuntu version first)
http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/puregnome

Since xubuntu-destkop is a metapackage removing it will not remove the other underlying packages. The link above tells you which ones you need