# How do I change the Ubuntu loading screen?

Tags: kubuntu

After I installed "kubuntu-desktop" my loading screen was changed:
[image: default ubuntu loading screen]

to this:
[image: kubuntu loading screen]

How do I change it back?

Comment: Check answer http://askubuntu.com/a/2292/158442.

Comment: @muru oh yes that's what I'm looking for. Maybe I couldn't reach that question because I didn't know it was called plymouth!! Thanks alot :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this using the `update-alternatives` command. You'll need to do this twice -- once to select the graphical boot splash, and once to select the fall-back text boot splash.

Open a console window and run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

Enter the selection number for the line containing `ubuntu-logo.plymouth`.

Next, run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config text.plymouth
```

Enter the selection number for the line containing `ubuntu-text.plymouth`.

Finally, update your initramfs. Run:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Reboot your PC, and you should see the Ubuntu boot splash return.

Comment: Eh, I was typing my answer and I see that muru pointed you to other answers.

Comment: yeah but anyways your answer worked like a charm!!! thank you so much :D :D

Comment: Oops. In fairness, @MinaMichael, Steve's answer includes the steps for the fallback boot screen - the answer I linked to missed that.

Comment: I tried his answer here before looking at the link so I didn't see.  Anyways I'm just happy things got fixed. Also your link is great if I wanted to come up with a custom bootscreen :D thanks to both of you guys :D